# What is a method for Spring to set field errors in BindingError with custom constraint like built-in constraint?(NotNull, ...)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm implementing custom hibernate constraint. But the result of BindingResult is different between my custom constraint and built-in constraint like @NotNull.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AtLeastOneElementNotBlank.AtLeastOneElementNotBlankValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface AtLeastOneElementNotBlank {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String[] fieldNames();   


    class AtLeastOneElementNotBlankValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AtLeastOneElementNotBlank, Object> {
        private String[] fieldNames;

        @Override
        public void initialize(AtLeastOneElementNotBlank constraintAnnotation) {
            this.fieldNames = constraintAnnotation.fieldNames();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            if (object == null) {
                return true;
            }

            try {
                for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
                    Object property = PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, fieldName);

                    if (property != null && !property.toString().equals("")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following code prints different results between custom constraint and built-in constraint:

```
if (validationResult.hasErrors()) 
            System.out.println("validationResult = " + validationResult);
```

> validationResult =
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'searchParam' on field 'searchKeyword': rejected
>   value [null]; codes
>   [NotBlank.searchParam.searchKeyword,NotBlank.searchKeyword,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [searchParam.searchKeyword,searchKeyword]; arguments []; default
>   message [searchKeyword]]; default message [xxx]
>
> validationResult =
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Error in object 'VAdCommonCode': codes
>   [AtLeastOneElementNotBlank.VAdCommonCode,AtLeastOneElementNotBlank];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [VAdCommonCode.,]; arguments []; default message
>   [],[Ljava.lang.String;@5065f440]; default message [xxx]

So, this code does not give any error information with my custom constraint.

```
 List<ValidationError> validationErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = validationResult.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
            ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError();
            validationError.setValidationCode(fieldError.getCode());
            validationError.setErrorMessage(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            validationError.setParamName(fieldError.getField());
            validationError.setRejectedValue(fieldError.getRejectedValue());

            validationErrors.add(validationError);
        }

@Data
class ValidationError {
    private String validationCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String paramName;
    private Object rejectedValue;
}
```

Is there a method for Spring to set field errors in BindingError with custom constraint?